# Configure error vtk on vs2010, win7 64bit?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64, vtk, qvtkwidget

I have this error when configure vtk on visual studio 2010, win7-64bit

The C compiler identification is unknow

The CXX compiler identification is unknown

Check if the system is big endian

Searching 16 bit integer

What's may be a problem?

Comment: Did you wait for the Configure to end? This can take 10 minutes or so.

Comment: you are not selecting a valid generator.